# Set Background Drawable for Action Bar not working with color in colors.xml

Tags: android, android-actionbar, colordrawable

I have the following code in my fragment:

```
 getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.Black));
```

when I click on a button in my fragment, it calls this code. I sets the actionbar to black. However if I change the color to `R.color.primaryColor` it keeps setting the actionbar to a medium grey color. Its so weird though. If I set it to `R.color.primaryColorDark`it gives me the same grey color.

I am using support action bar which is actually a toolbar.

Am I missing something obvious here?

[EDIT]

Ok i have discovered if I used the android colors liek `Color.BLUE` it works fine, it is giving me the grey color when i use `R.colors.mycustomcolor`

here is my colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="primaryColorDark">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="accentColor">#1976D6</color>
</resources>
```

and when i set the action bar to any of these colors they come out grey.

I only have ONE color.xml so its not taking the wrong color for a different layout type.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that to do this!!

**Here is the code:**

```
public override void OnAttach(Activity activity) {
    base.OnAttach(activity);
    var colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
    activity.ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

   var titleId = activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id","android");
    var abTitle = activity.FindViewById<TextView>(titleId);
    abTitle.SetTextColor(Color.Black);

  }
```

**OR here another one**

n a `Fragment`, the `ActionBar` view is usually handled through overriding the:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

callback method; after making sure you have called `SetHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `OnCreate()`.

It is possible that you are getting that `NullReferenceException` because `OnCreateView()` is being called before the `ActionBar` layout has been inflated.

**Typically**, this is what the method will look like:

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //Stops the menu being reinflated on configuration changes
    if(!menu.HasVisibleItems) 
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MenuLayout, menu);

    var myMenuItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.MyMenuItem);
    //Do stuff with your menu items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it has to work

```
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor)));
```